# You'll know afterwards, when I get mad. [Analysis of 'when']

Tags: conjunctions, relative-clauses, antecedents

American sitcom *That '70s Show* has these lines ([YouTube](https://youtu.be/M_FxIPEdXKM?t=83)):

> **Eric:** So, uh, for future reference, do I have to ask you, uh, before I go out with my friends?

> **Donna:** No. Uh yes. Sometimes.

> **Eric:** So, uh, how will I know which times?

> **Donna:** Well, you'll know **afterwards**, **when** I get mad.

Is *when* a relative word taking *afterwards* as antecedent?

If you think this analysis is wrong, please provide your own analysis.

If you think this is right, please explain why it has to be.

Comment: It's a joke.  After one of the times that you should have asked is when I will get mad.

Comment: @HotLicks Do I look like I don't understand the line?

Comment: You need a noun antecedent for *when* to act as a relative (where it means *in which* or *on which*).

Answer (score 2):

> Donna: Well, you'll know afterwards, when I get mad.

> Is when a relative word taking afterwards as antecedent?

When, adverb = the time at which

This is spoken “Well, you'll know afterwards, *[slight pause]* when I get mad.” = “Well, you'll know afterwards, **which is when I will get mad**.” or “Well, you'll know afterwards **because afterwards is the time at which I will get mad.**”

“*when I get mad*” is in apposition to “**afterwards**” – you can omit either “when I get mad” or “afterwards” (but not both.)

**Afterwards** is an adverb, and thus “when I get mad” is a descriptive adverbial phrase, explaining the meaning of “afterwards” – it is thus ‘relative’.

Consider:

“John, the man who owns the shop, is very ill.” You can omit "John" or "the man who owns the shop"

Comment: Yes: _afterwards_ and _when I get mad_ are in apposition, not _afterwards_ and _when_. The Wikipedia example is incorrect.

Comment: Is there any reason for inserting "will" before "get"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What Wikipedia example?

Comment: @JK2 That cited in the previous answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Please explain how the example is incorrect.

Comment: @JK2 'in the afternoon' and 'when nobody was home' are in apposition in this example (though this is obviously not an equivalence apposition; compare 'Judd Trump, an incredibly talented snooker placer,'). With a strictly defined antecedent, the related pro-form is a word or phrase that can take the place of another word (or word group) in a sentence rather than merely reference it. You can't substitute 'when' for 'in the afternoon'; you need a when-clause.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But you normally can't substitute relative words for their antecedents, either. Maybe you're conflating apposition and relativization. If so, why?

Comment: @JK2 If you care to look back through the associated threads, you'll see that the existence of different specifying definitions of 'apposition' has been addressed. 'Antecedent' is another term with conflicting definitions; in a question involving antecedents, the precise terminology chosen needs to be spelled out. Then asking commenters to explain their stances would be less improper.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the "afterwards" is an antecedent to the "when" in this case.

One of the examples of an antecedent that is followed by a corresponding proform, given in [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_(grammar)) is

> d. He arrived *in the afternoon*, **when** nobody was home. - Prepositional phrase as antecedent

where "in the afternoon" is a prepositional phrase that is the antecedent to "when". The difference between this example and the one in "Well, you'll know afterwards, when I get mad.", is that this example is in the past, hence, "when nobody *was* home". In "Well, you'll know afterwards, when I get mad.", the "afterwards" is in the future, so the *present simple* is used in "when I get mad".

As we can see in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_(grammar))'s grammar section

> The present simple is used to refer to events in the future which are certain because they are facts, or because there is a clear or fixed schedule or timetable.

Comment: Although the wiki marks "in the afternoon" as antecedent of "when", I'm not sure if the antecedent is "in the afternoon" or "the afternoon". Take for example _He waited until the afternoon, when nobody was home_. Here, I think the antecedent is "the afternoon", not "until the afternoon". If so, why can't we say that the antecedent in the wiki example is also "the afternoon", not "in the afternoon"?

Comment: If the antecedent were "afternoon", then "when nobody was at home" would have to be adjectival. In that case "in the afternoon when nobody was at home" would not have a comma and be a complete noun phrase, In that case it would have to be "**on** the afternoon when nobody was at home" and that would have to refer to a previously mentioned afternoon. However, we see that what is meant is that "He arrived in the afternoon and he arrived when nobody was at home" - both are adverbial.

Comment: @Greybeard I don't understand your dichotomy between "adjectival" and "adverbial". (1) Who said the antecedent is "afternoon"? I was comparing "the afternoon" (not "afternoon") and "in the afternoon" as antecedent. (2) Just because "when nobody was home" is a supplementary clause separated by a comma doesn't mean that it's an adverbial clause. If it were, you could place it before the main clause, which you can't.

Comment: @JK2 You ask *(1) Who said the antecedent is "afternoon"? I was comparing "the afternoon" (not "afternoon") and "in the afternoon" as antecedent.* but you wrote  *I'm not sure if the antecedent is **"in the afternoon"** or **"the afternoon"***. In the sentence, there is no difference between **Afternoon** (noun) and **the afternoon** (noun phrase).

Comment: @JK2: I don't think the antecedent/proform framework applies here, as *when nobody was home* is not a proform by any definition I can imagine. In any case, these are two adverbial ways to say the same thing: *He arrived in the afternoon. He arrived when nobody was home.* Same here: *He waited until the afternoon. He waited until when nobody was home.* In the first set, the preposition participates in the apposition: *in the afternoon* = *when nobody was home*. In the second, it does not: *the afternoon* = *when nobody was home*. But in neither case is *when nobody was home* a relative clause.

Comment: @TinfoilHat If it's not a relative clause, what is it?

Comment: Maybe we should we pick a particular grammar for terms, but... // **Relative (adjective) clause** (*when* is a relative pronoun): *He arrived on an afternoon **when nobody was home**.* // **Adverb clause** (*when* is a subordinating conjunction): *He arrived in the afternoon, **when nobody was home**.* //  **Noun (fused/free relative) clause** (*when* is a fused relative): *He waited until **when nobody was home**.*